# How do i use a servlet in my grails app?

Tags: grails

I need to use some connectors which are actually servlets. How can I do this in Grails and what about the web.xml? How do I configure the url of the servlet?

I actually have a Spring application here and I am trying to convert it into a partial Grails app. I have a connector servlet in the spring-app, which I wish to use here but the mapping is a must to call the servlet in the gsp file. How can I do this? I basically need to know where the xml file is in case of Grails.

Comment: This question is too board, u need to narrow down you question to more specific part of what don't you understand, what you tried.

Comment: @Churk Thanks churk for the reply i have edited the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the `web.xml` file, you can run:

```
grails install-templates
```

Then, the file can be found in:

```
<yourapp>/src/templates/war/web.xml
```

Edit this as usual to add `<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>` sections, then put your servlet code in:

```
<yourapp>src/java/your/package/structure/WhateverServlet.java
```

and you should be good to go

Comment: Thank you, i tried this but due to some reason i get a 404 resource not avilable.I don't know why, And the mapping is absolutely the same as the one in my spring application where the same mapping works perfectly.ALso the folder structure is the same. I am calling this servlet in a javascript from my gsp page.Actually this same page is a html in case of my old spring application.

Comment: Make sure to put the url-mapping of your servlet before grails dispatcher servlet

Answer (score 3):

If you are within a grails-plugin, then you have a defined place within your `*GrailsPlugin.groovy`, where to do such things. E.g.  Look at the auto generated closure:

```
def doWithWebDescriptor = { xml ->
   []
}
```

In here you can add your custom servlet configurations:

```
    def servlets = xml.'servlet'
    servlets[servlets.size() - 1] + {
        servlet {
            'servlet-name'('yourName')
            'servlet-class'('yourpackage.YourClass')
        }
    }

    def mappings = xml.'servlet-mapping'
    mappings[mappings.size() - 1] + {
        'servlet-mapping' {
            'servlet-name'('yourName')
            'url-pattern'('/yourPattern/*')
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

good news and bad news, and I myself have asked this question here before. With spring application you can have multiple level of URI such as domain.com/abc/def/efg/abc vs grails has a lot of issue with anything beyond domain.com/controller/view. here is a link to my original question: [Grails URL mapping cause error on GSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262867/grails-url-mapping-cause-error-on-gsp)

The good news is, you don't need to deal with XML mapping, grails does it seemlessly by controllers and views. So you are almost limited to domain.com/YouController/YourView/SomeParamteres... but if thats all you'll need, all u have to do is create grails-app/Controller/SomethingController.groovy and you automatically have domain.com/Something